# How to find the Files of SharePoint hosted app deployed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need change the a js file which deployed as part of SharePoint hosted app in SharePoint Online.

Please let me know where files are saved after deploying the SharePoint hosted app in SharePoint Online.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in a virtual folder named Scripts in the app web. However, these files are designed not to manually edited.

To edit the files you need to update them in the Visual Studio project where they were originally created, then create a new version of the app package, and then upload the new version of the app package to the tenant app catalog.

You can find documentation that describes how to build and deploy SharePoint-hosted Add-ins (Apps) by following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins